Why are .ini files not saving my changes?
I need help figuring out how to save the changes I made to my .ini file.
Every time I hit “save” or ctrl+s it ends up turning into “save as” I don’t want to “save as”! I just want to save the file and close out the notepad. I can’t even see the properties of the file, every time I right click I'm left with “open” or “copy”… I’m on Windows 11 and I’m trying to set up ISTA software to diagnose my BMW but it’s frustrating when the .ini file won’t save my changes to it in Notepad.
C:\Users\knemr\Downloads\ISTA_4.32.1 extracted I can edit the files in the first folder but when I get in the subfolders past C:\Users\knemr\Downloads\ISTA_4.32.1 extracted\ISTA_v4.32.15.24911.7z I have limited options. And it is in the downloads folder, not the Windows SSD. I tried the document method where I copied the .ini file and modified it there, but the option was greyed out as soon as I wanted to paste it into the original subfolder. Also, how do I check if the software was installed on the program files?
I also downloaded and copied all the files. But even in the copy it still doesn't allow me to save my changes as it goes to "save as". I tried Notepad++ but it won't let me even delete or edit the text in it.
The file I'm trying to modify is 5 sub files deep C:\Users\knemr\Downloads\ISTA_4.32.1 extracted\ISTA_v4.32.15.24911.7z\Rheingold\Ediabas\BIN



Heya.  I have a couple of questions.  The first is, are you editing the files while they are still in the archive (.7z) file? Second, what permissions are the files set with for your user?  Can you check both the archive file and the .ini file you're trying to alter?
I doubt that the file still being in its archive file would affect it, but you can never be too certain.  If your account doesn't have permission to alter it (unlikely, but possible), then it will only let you save the changes in a separate file.

I believe it is not in the archive (.7z) file.  I extracted the first folder but I didn't extract the subfolder with the .ini file I'm trying to modify (as people who have the same software never did and still edit the .ini file somehow). I altered the permissions to full control I believe in File Explorer also my laptop user is the administrator. But if there's another way to change permissions please do tell! I tried the method where I copy the .ini file and changed it. But it won't let me paste the copy into the subfolder as the paste button is greyed out.

Your paths have a .7z in them, though – are you sure that's really a subfolder and not a second 7z archive?

god dam u were right!!! im such a fool for not extracting those
